# Regex optional recursive pattern

Tags: regex

I don't know how to catch an optional pattern in a string.

To parse this string :
`Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.4; Nexus 5 Build/KTU84P)`

I use this pattern which exactly what I need) :

```
/^([^\/\s]*)\/([^\s]*)(\s\(([^()]*|\([^()]*\)*)\))?/

# returns
# 1.    Dalvik
# 2.    1.6.0
# 3.    (Linux; U; Android 4.4.4; Nexus 5 Build/KTU84P)
# 4.    Linux; U; Android 4.4.4; Nexus 5 Build/KTU84P
```

But this string can have first patter multiple times, like :
`Bonobo/1.0.3; Multipass/1.5.2; Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.4; Nexus 5 Build/KTU84P)`

And what I'd like to get is :

```
# 1.    Bonobo
# 3.    1.0.3
# 4.    Multipass
# 5.    1.5.2
# 6.    Dalvik
# 7.    1.6.0
# 8.    (Linux; U; Android 4.4.4; Nexus 5 Build/KTU84P)
# 9.    Linux; U; Android 4.4.4; Nexus 5 Build/KTU84P
```

But after many many tries, I can't figure it out.

Any idea?

Many thanks.

Comment: What language do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `\G` anchor for repeated strings (ie, the strings which are matched by the same pattern).

```
\G\s*([^\/\s]*)\/([^\s;]*);?(\s\(([^()]*|\([^()]*\)*)\))?
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/uT5cC0/1)